# Can I use Google analytics to get page view stats for several pages over time

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for a way in Google Analytics to get separate page view counts for a number of pages, aggregated by day, week or month

For example:

```
      Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4
Page1 34   45   56   78
Page2 54   67   75   34
Page3 56   23   56   43
```

Can GA produce this kind of thing in a single report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Hang on there, I'll try to be short. There's not an exact way to do this, but here's the thing that most resembles this:

1. **Create a custom report**
   To do this, open the dashboard report for your site, and in the sidebar click "Custom Reporting -> Manage Custom Reports -> Create new custom report"
2. **On the new screen you need to add one metric and one dimension**
   Drag and drop a PageViews metric (under the Site Usage category) and a Page dimension (under the Content category). The whole thing should look like this:
   [image]
3. **If you click Preview Report**, it should give you pageviews per page, just as you want, but it will be for a predefined period (span of the two latest weeks)
   [image]
4. **Open the dropdown in the upper left corner to select a different time period**, click the Timeline tab, then check the "Compare to past" checkbox. Fill in the periods you need to compare and click Apply.
   [image]
5. **The report should give you page views for the periods you have chosen** (per page) and a percentage change between the respective periods
   [image]

The downside to all of this is that you have to select periods every time you view the report, because there's no way to hardcode a period. The other disadvantage is that you can compare only two periods. I'm not aware of any way to overcome this, but I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed answer. I'm going to try this out later today when i get a moment

Comment: This is probably the best answer we're going to get to this question. Not exactly what I was after but it is pretty ingenious and will most likely save me quite a bit of time.