# Using Google Analytics: Pageviews per page per month? How?

Tags: google-analytics

First, this question was basically asked in July of 2010:

[Can I use Google analytics to get page view stats for several pages over time](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/can-i-use-google-analytics-to-get-page-view-stats-for-several-pages-over-time)

I'm re-asking it in the hopes that Analytics has changed sufficiently since then as to enable this feature, or that fresh eyes three years later might yield a better answer.

Here's what I'm trying to do:  I ultimately want to generate a table (which I'll import into Excel) where the left column contains the names of the pages, and the top row contains the months of the year.  So if A2 contains "/somepageURL/", B2 would contain the number of pageviews it received in June, C2 would be the pageviews in July, D2 would be August, and so on.  A3 would contain "/anotherpageURL/" and the cells going across would be the pageviews for THAT one.

I can find a pile of Custom Reports I can build that do something that's sort of close-ish, but taking it from what GA offers to what I actually need is a few hours of cutting and pasting data between spreadsheets.

Closest I've gotten is that the leftmost column lists the months, the column next to it lists the page URL, and the cells show the pageviews per month.  But to track the thousands of pages in the website, to get what I need I'd have to take D4 and paste it into B4, E5 would have to get pasted to B5 and so on.

If my description isn't clear, the link above is to a post that starts with a table that's similar to what I'm after (although it groups by day instead of by month).

Comment: That's the only way I'm aware of... pull each time period and paste together.  This approach works well if you have the same URLs over time, but forces you to deal with content not in all the time periods compared.  Painstaking if dealing with 1000's of dynamic URLs. Would love to hear of a better way.

Comment: How did you get the close-ish dataset using the Custom Reports?

Answer (score 1):

GA Data Grabber allows you to manipulate Google Analytics data in Excel.  There's a free trial if you're unsure if it'll meet your needs.
http://www.gadatagrabbertool.com/

If you are familiar with Python, I recommend using the Pandas module which allows you to access the Google Analytics API directly.  This way you can use the Pandas data frames to manipulate the data anyway you want and export the csv to Excel.

Pandas GA tutorial: http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandas-google-analytics.html

Answer (score 0):

I am no Google Analytics expert, but from an Excel point of view, it sounds like you should be able to use a pivot table to get the data into the format you require. Highlight all your data and create a pivot table. you should the be able to move clumns and rows into the layout ou require with just a few clicks. Just Google something like 'create pivot table' and check it out.

Sorry to have wasted your time if you've already considered the above